# Can I add custom attributes to button html. Will it work in all browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

```
<button id="save" custom-field="false">
```

Can I define my own custom attribute for button markup like stated above? Will it work on all browsers?

Basically, the problem I have is that the above save button redirects to an AJAX call, which, if successful, then redirects to some other page.
I have added an alert on window.onbeforeunload. I don't want this alert to pop up when the redirect is due to successful ajax call on click of the save button.

So, the above fix is that on successful ajax, I set the `custom-field` to true and in my window.onbeforeunload code I alert only if `custom-field` false.

Answer (score 10):

Yes you can use jquery **[.data](https://api.jquery.com/data/)** for adding custom attribute.

It can be used to add any custom arbitrary data

```
<button id="save" data-myAttribute="myAttribute">
```

You can retrieve it using

```
$( "#save" ).data( "myAttribute" ); // myAttribute
```

or using javascript

```
document.getElementById('save').setAttribute('mydata','myData');
```

retrieve it using

```
document.getElementById('save').getAttribute('mydata');
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `data-attribute` .

For Eg:

```
<button id="save" data-field="false">
```

Read more about [**data-attribute**](https://www.sitepoint.com/use-html5-data-attributes/)

You can easily retrieve the data attribute value in jquery using `.data()` or `.attr('data-field')`

Comment: @user2713255 yes it is .and it is reliable . thats why prefer this

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can add custom field in any element and access it like below when need

```
<button id="save" data-field="false">

    var custFieldValue=$('#save').attr('data-field');
```